# What does "理所应当的美好" mean?

Tags: translation

我们确信， 在 Mac 的世界中， 你只需放飞自己的想象力。 享受一切**理所应当的美好**。

So 享受一切理所应当的美好。translates to: Enjoy all beauty as it should be?

Sentence is from here: http://pinyin.sogou.com/mac/

[Other Examples with 理所应当的美好](http://www.baidu.com/s?ie=utf-8&f=8&rsv_bp=1&tn=baidu&wd=%22%E7%90%86%E6%89%80%E5%BA%94%E5%BD%93%E7%9A%84%E7%BE%8E%E5%A5%BD%22&rsv_enter=1&rsv_sug3=3&rsv_sug4=342&rsv_sug2=0&inputT=1040)

[More Examples](http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%22%E7%90%86%E6%89%80%E5%BA%94%E5%BD%93%E7%9A%84%E7%BE%8E%E5%A5%BD%22&pn=10&oq=%22%E7%90%86%E6%89%80%E5%BA%94%E5%BD%93%E7%9A%84%E7%BE%8E%E5%A5%BD%22&ie=utf-8)

Comment: This is the kind of nonsense only exists in Chinese. It takes a toll on my two digit iq every time I read it.

Comment: 名副其实 or 货真价实 maybe more appropriate than 理所应当.

Comment: It's a good try on lyrics. I'm serious.

Answer (score 7):

享受一切理所应当的美好 = enjoy all the beauty you deserve

Here, 'beauty' refers to the nice features that Mac and Sogou provide.

However, this expression seems to be a little bit strange. Usually, we do not put the word 理所应当的 before a noun. For example, instead of saying '这是理所应当的美好', one should say '这份美好是理所应当的'.

Comment: So does context change the meaning? Here's an example from Baidu: 有人说:世上最愚蠢的事情就是在金钱和爱情面前卖弄自尊无数次地纠结后,发现有些问题无从解决,原本认为的那么理所应当的美好的理解,到此却真的是种理想. It doesn't make as much sense to me here.

Comment: @Steve As a well educated native speaker, I would definitely mark this sentence as wrong if I were a Chinese teacher. If you encounter a random sentence (which makes you confused) from a random place, you may simply forget about it. I think it is a good practice for learners to accept language input only from trusted resources.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like badly translated Chinese...

「享受一切理所应当的美好」 could be translated from "Enjoy all the beautiful things happened (to you)" or "Enjoy all the beautiful things that you deserved".

Write as 「理所当然地享受美好的一切」sounds more natural to me,

it tells us that 'The things are already be' and 'they are also our expected'. The translation "Enjoy all the beautiful things that you deserved" is better.

Comment: 美好 does not only mean "beauty", but also including "good in virtue", etc.

Answer (score 2):

in this sentence, it's more like "enjoy the beauty as you deserve it"

of course @Opteron 's translation is right, but the expression is not strange at all from my view as a native Chinese speaker

meanwhile if we use 这份美好是理所应当的, then this part should be in a separate sentence. we don't have the same grammar as English. if one is trying to connect this part with a previous instead of starting a new one, adjective should be before noun